# Don't download images while scraping

Tags: perl, web-scraping, lwp, lwp-useragent

I am using LWP::UserAgent to scrape some pages. To save bandwidth, I don't want to download images and other media on the page, I am only interested in the text.

Can't find anything in the documentation which can help me with this. Please help

Comment: I used `LWP::UserAgent` all the time and it never downloads images, only the text. It also does not download any AJAX content.

Answer (score 4):

While you don't show any code I assume that you follow in your scraping just the `<a href=` links but not any `<img src=` or similar links (i.e. video, css, favicon..)  which are obviously images and other types of data you are not interested in.

Unfortunately with a `<a href=` link it is impossible to find out up front what kind of data this will be. You might make some guess based on a typical suffix of the resource (i.e. `image.png`) but you can not be sure what it really is. This information you get only once you access the resource, for example by checking the `Content-type` declared in the response header. LWP offers a way to inspect the response header before downloading the full resource by adding a handler for the `response_header` phase. From [the documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::UserAgent#response_header-sub-my-response-ua-h-_):

> response_header => sub { my($response, $ua, $h) = @_; ... }
>   This handler is called right after the response headers have been received, but before any content data. The handler might set up handlers for data and **might croak to abort the request**.

This can be used to stop receiving the response for any non-text content:

```
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
$ua->add_handler( response_header => sub {
    my $resp = shift;
    die "no text" if $resp->content_type !~m{^text/};
});
my $resp = $ua->get('http://example.com/some-image.gif');
```